# how can I skip the first few lines of a text file using the raku IO.lines.race construct

Tags: raku

I am trying to read a text file using raku with the IO.lines.race construct. For example

```
for $file.IO.lines.race
{
  #do something, such as
  my ($a,$b)=.split(" ");
}
```

How can I skip the, say, first three lines of the text file?

Thanks!

Tao

Answer (score 10):

Update: As recommended by Elizabeth Mattijsen it is more efficient use skip instead of tail.

```
for $file.IO.lines.skip(3).race
```

There is a [tail](https://docs.raku.org/routine/tail) routine you can use:

```
for $file.IO.lines.tail(*-3).race
{
  #do something, such as
  my ($a,$b)=.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: `skip` also works, and is much more efficient: `for $file.IO.lines.skip(3).race`

Answer (score 5):

The answer above by Lukas Valle is perfectly fine; you can use [skip](https://docs.raku.org/routine/skip) to skip the lines you don't need.
However, I can't help but indicate that case goes much better with other functional constructs such as map:

```
$file.IO.lines.skip(3).race.map( .split(" ") );
```

That way, you can chain several operations together without creating different loops. Of course, in Raku TIMTOWDI, so a `for` loop (or several) is perfectly fine.

Also, in this case I would really time how much the loop, or `map`, is going to take. For files that don't have many lines, `race` is not going to give you much, and it might even be slower, due to overhead. If your intention is to beat the clock a bit, [`IO::Handle.Supply`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle#method_Supply) is probably going to be a bit faster.